# Find Subdocument by Id based on value in parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given that I have a document of the following structure:

```
{
    selectedId: ObjectId("57b5fb2d7b41dde99009bc75"),
    children: [
        {_id: ObjectId("57b5fb2d7b41dde99009bc75"), val: 10},
        {_id: ObjectId("57b5fb2d7b41dde99009bc75"), val: 20},
    ]
}
```

where the parent value "selectedId" always references one of the children Id, how do I just get the child subdocument where _id = selectedId?

I attempted:

```
parentModel.findOne({'selectedId': 'this.children._id'})
```

however, as I now know, the second string is taken as a literal. So how do I reference the parent's field in the query?

**Edit**: obviously, this could be done with two queries, getting the parent's "selectedId" value and then querying again. However, I want to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregation framework, in particular leverage the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operators to return the child subdocument. The following example shows this:

```
parentModel.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "children": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$children",
                            "as": "item",
                            "cond": {
                                "$eq": ["$$item._id", "$selectedId"]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(callback);
```